# Looking for a way to change the default shapefile label in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, labeling

Is there a way to change ArcGIS's default shapefile label `Font: Aerial Size: 8` to something we are using over and over again? As shown in attached screen shot, I'd like to include a label expression in addition to a saved text symbol:

[image]

It would be very helpful to save the couple of steps it takes to change labels as I am working with hundreds of maps / shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default symbol for labeling cannot be set in ArcGIS.  You get what you get.  This is a common enhancement request though and I suggest voting for it on ideas.arcgis.com.

Comment: Yeah, this is what appears to be reality... yet another example of Esri's planned obsolescence. It would be awesome to get a copy of Esri's "common enhancement requests" log going back a decade or two and see how it compares to their software releases. If i sound bitter about Esri's business practices, it's only because i am. QGIS is looking more and more attractive all the time. http://www.google.com/search?q=esri+%22planned+obsolescence%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I made my ideas.arcgis.com comment sincerely.  We take entries on ideas.arcgis.com seriously and incorporate them into our development.

Comment: Thanks Craig, is there a tool in ArcMap allowing users to click and submit ideas while in the middle of the issue they are working with?  Also, i found an interesting link on Esri reviews that may be of interest here http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Esri-Reviews-E4043.htm?sort.sortType=OR&sort.ascending=true

Comment: ArcMap does not have an in-app feedback mechanism at this time.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS 10
 click advanced on the expression

```
Function FindLabel ( [difference] )
  FindLabel = "<FNT name='Gill Sans MT' size='20'>" & [difference]& "</FNT>"
End Function
```

[image]

Save and that will save you time - can be automated with arcpy

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, I tried both but defaults labels are unchanged. I read through [Advanced Settings Utility](http://oi56.tinypic.com/1j2649.jpg) and  [Advanced Settings Registry Keys](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B0ujPOzxeGqeMzE3MjEzNGQtNWY5MC00NGRhLWJkY2MtYjMwNGM1YWZkZTYz&hl=en) but didn't see anything about changing default label settings.

Comment: Screenhot to help explain for you label to change - rather than the default aerial it is no Gill Sans MT and size 20pt.

Comment: i think i didn't explain fully... I already have a label expression i need to use every time called `[FAC_TYPE]  & " " & [ROUTE]  & " " & [SEGMENT_NO]` in addition to using a saved label and having "Overlap Labels" turned on as well. [example](http://i.imgur.com/3pz0I.jpg)When i check "Advanced" it goes back to the old default next time i add a new shapefile to the mxd (i am adding hundreds) Unless i am missing how adding your code `Function FindLabel ( [difference] )
  FindLabel = "<FNT name='Gill Sans MT' size='20'.....` would change the defaults i'm at a loss to understand how this works.

Comment: Is the Advanced box ticked? as that Function FindLabel ( [difference] ) FindLabel = "<FNT name='Gill Sans MT' size='20' is VBScript not a basic expression.

Comment: Yes, Advantaged is turned on with `Function FindLabel ( [FAC_TYPE], [ROUTE], [SEGMENT_NO] )
  FindLabel = Function FindLabel ( [FAC_TYPE] &  " "  &  [ROUTE] &  " "  &  [SEGMENT_NO] )  FindLabel = "<FNT name='Gill Sans MT' size='20'>" & [FAC_TYPE] &  " "  &  [ROUTE] &  " "  &  [SEGMENT_NO]]& "</FNT>" End Function
End Function` which gives error.... I really wish there was an affordable [alternative to Maplex](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=maplex+)

Comment: I've used the HTML tags on labels without having the advanced box checked.  I don't think you need to wrap the expression in the FindLabel function.  Try just putting "<FNT name='Gill Sans MT' size='20'>" & [FAC_TYPE] & " " & [ROUTE] & " " & [SEGMENT_NO] & "</FNT>"   You were most likely getting an error because you had an extra ] next to SEGMENT_NO.  I'm unaware of a way to keep overlap labels turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do two things since you are wanting the expression to be saved, because I haven't tested this out...

Once you set everything up, the label placement properties, expressions, font size/colour etc..., from the Labels tab in that layers Properties window, click the Label Styles button and then click Save.

That will save the label style with its current placement properties and everything you set up and can be used on another layer when you need it, but as for the expression, I am not so sure this will save that. From the label expression window, you may be stuck with using the Save/Load buttons to constantly import your previous expression for use again.

Sorry I can't answer the 'default' setting part of the question.